# Swift - Add an item in firestore only if it is not already there

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am following a tutorial and I am trying to save to Firestore a list of Favorite products (different from the tutorial). Items are being added but if I press again the "Add to favorites" button it adds the same item again in Firestore and I want to add the item only once. This is my code

```swift
struct addToFavoritesButton : View {
    @ObservedObject var favoriteListener = FavoriteListener()
    //binding variable get the info from another variable does not have a value in it self
    @Binding var showAlert: Bool
    @Binding var averageColor:Color
    @Binding var complementColor:Color
    
    var product : Product
    var body : some View {
        Button {
            showAlert.toggle()
            self.addItemToFavorites()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "heart")
                .font(.title3)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: 50)
                .background(self.complementColor)
                .foregroundColor(self.averageColor)
                .cornerRadius(25)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Adăugat la preferate."), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }//: ALERT
    }//: BODY
    private func addItemToFavorites() {
        
        var favorite: Favorite!
        
        if self.favoriteListener.favorite != nil {//deja am un id de favorite in firestore atasat clientului
            let isInFavorites = isProductInFavorites(product: product)
            if isInFavorites == false {
                favorite = self.favoriteListener.favorite
            }
        } else { //daca nu am deja un id de fav il creez
            favorite = Favorite()
            favorite.ownerId = "123"
            favorite.id = UUID().uuidString
        }
        favorite.add(self.product)
        favorite.saveFavoritesToFirestore()
    }
    
    func isProductInFavorites(product: Product) -> Bool {
      let db = Firestore.firestore()
      let docRef = db.collection("Favorite").document(product.id)

      var isInFavorites = false
      docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
          isInFavorites = true
        } else {
          isInFavorites = false
        }
      }
      return isInFavorites
    }
}
```

I've tried something (isProductInFavorites) but it's not working. It is still adding the item again in Firestore. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are a number of ways you can do this. You can either make this task idempotent or not. An idempotent task would create this favorite one time regardless of how many times you pressed the button. This would likely require the `UUID` of the favorite to be constant. Or you can take your approach and check to see if its favorited before favoriting it. This is a more expensive and a more inefficient task (requires a read in addition to the write). You can either perform a Firestore transaction that does the read and write in one shot or you can piece it out like you have here.

Comment: The problem with your code is that you haven't made the read function `isProductInFavorites(product:)` asynchronous. In Swift, you must either use a completion handler to return the `Bool` or, since you're using SwiftUI, make this function conform to `async/await`. They both achieve the same outcome in different ways. So to fix your immediate problem, you must make `isProductInFavorites(product:)` an `async` function. But if you really want to learn programming, consider the bigger picture and what the most efficient way would be.

Comment: Thanks @trndjc. Since you strongly advised not to use the isProductInFavorites() I discarded the idea. I found another solution. Not sure if it's idempotent, but I will read some more about idempotent tasks.

Comment: Favorite is a document so it has a unique id, and the favorite document has an array of products.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here, maybe it will help somebody.

```swift
struct addToFavoritesButton : View {
    @ObservedObject var favoriteListener = FavoriteListener()
    //binding variable get the info from another variable does not have a value in it self
    @Binding var showAlert: Bool
    @Binding var averageColor:Color
    @Binding var complementColor:Color
    
    var product : Product
    var body : some View {
        Button {
            showAlert.toggle()
            self.addItemToFavorites()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "heart")
                .font(.title3)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: 50)
                .background(self.complementColor)
                .foregroundColor(self.averageColor)
                .cornerRadius(25)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Adăugat la preferate."), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }//: ALERT
    }//: BODY
    
    private func addItemToFavorites() {
        
        var favorite: Favorite!
        
        if self.favoriteListener.favorite != nil {
            favorite = self.favoriteListener.favorite
        } else {
            favorite = Favorite()
            favorite.ownerId = "123"
            favorite.id = UUID().uuidString
        }
        
        if !favorite.items.contains(where: { $0.id == self.product.id }) {
            favorite.add(self.product)
            favorite.saveFavoritesToFirestore()
        }
    }
}
```